# Como adicionar arquivos de javascript de acordo com o viewport/device?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando o script [skrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) em um site e ao abrir em celulares a barra de rolagem não está funcionando (é como se o touch do celular ficasse bloqueado). 
Eu queria saber como desabilitar scripts quando o usuário acessar de celulares, já que eu não quero usar o skrollr nessa situação. Seria como um media query para javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A forma mais simples é ler o conteúdo da *string* [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) do navegador, fazer um teste para verificar se a mesma contém a indicação de dispositivo móvel e agir em conformidade:

**JavaScript**

```js
if ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // utilizador em dispositivo móvel, agir em conformidade.
}
else {

    // não é dispositivo móvel

    // adicionar a tag de script ao DOM
    var script  = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src  = "caminho/para/skrollr.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // iniciar o skrollr aqui...
}
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Nyw2h/)

---

<sup>**Nota:** Não existe um método à prova de bala para resolver esta questão. Para a solução que indiquei, a string do UA pode ser manipulada levando a uma detecção incorrecta. Claro que não vejo isso a acontecer com o comum dos utilizadores.</sup>

---

Outras técnicas comuns é a detecção da resolução do ecrã e o suporte a touch, mas nos dias de hoje os novos portáteis já vem com suporte a touch e muitos dos tablets suportam resoluções elevadas, o que acaba por inviabilizar estes métodos.

Answer (score 2):

Há duas maneiras: server-side ou client-side.

### Server-side

Depende fortemente da linguagem. Algumas já possuem bibliotecas bem estabelecidas para detecção do client a partir do cabeçalho da requisição HTTP. Se suas páginas são geradas dinamicamente, uma boa abordagem seria fornecer uma versão sem a declaração do script.

### Client-side

Se suas páginas são estaticamente servidas (isto é, HTML puro), a melhor opção é servi-las sem a chamada ao script. Você pode, então, detectar através de um pequeno script customizado se o browser é mobile; caso não seja, adiciona dinamicamente o script do skrollr.js.

*Como*, exatamente, você vai detectar se o browser é mobile fica à sua escolha; você pode utilizar bibliotecas prontas, detectar palavras-chave no `userAgent` ou então usar serviços como o http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/.

Aproveito para lembrar que a detecção por tamanho nem sempre é uma boa ideia; tablets e alguns laptops possuem alta resolução **E** interatividade touchscreen, o que pode frustrar seus planos. Ainda, citei apenas métodos que funcionam crossbrowser; como você mesmo já citou, media query e algumas outras tecnologias novas podem ser utilizadas também, mas com o custo de não funcionarem em browsers legados.

Espero ter ajudado!